# How can I use Siri to select between multiple email addresses?

Tags: email, siri

When using Siri to send an email to a contact with multiple email addresses, I can't find a way to select one of the addresses in a hands-free way (without clicking with my finger).  Siri reads out the two addresses, and then gives me a voice prompt to pick one, but when I say one of them back it just loops back to the "Which email address for..." prompt.

Anyone know what to say here?  I've tried just saying the domain of the address, "one", "the first one", the entire email address, but none of them work.

Comment: Have you also tried saying the address's label (e.g. "home", "work", "main")?

Comment: <humor> Try this again, but say ``sudo`` first. </humor>

Comment: @djacobson - good idea...but it doesn't look like the iPhone lets you specify a label for email addresses.  They all just show up as "email" with no way to edit them.  The addresses in Outlook are labeled, but those labels don't get shown on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is what i saw when i asked SIRI to send a mail to a contact with multiple address, i then chose 'Home' and siri asked me what should she send!. It was pretty straight forward IMHO, so i suggest you try to disable/enable SIRI, if that doesn't work, then i think you will have to restore iOS option. Hope this helps mate

[image]

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response.  You have the right answer for a regular contact.  My problem is that my contacts are linked to an Outlook/Exchange server, which doesn't support associating a "type".

Answer (score 0):

When you are looking at the Contact information on the iPhone, tap 'Edit' (top right corner).

Then tap the *label* next to the email address for that contact, and you should see this:

[image: iPhone Contact Email Label]

If you tap *that* Edit button (shown here; again, top right), you can choose "+ Add Custom Label" to make your own.

(That's how it works for .Mac/MobileMe/iCloud and Gmail/Google Apps, I *assume* it is the same for Outlook.)

Siri definitely uses those labels when choosing which email address to use.

> (Aside: I have actually gone through many of my contacts and if I have more than one email address for them, I put the *primary* one in the email field, and move the other to the "Notes" in case it stops working. Ditto for phone numbers. If I always call you on your cell phone, or always call your work number, the other numbers move to the notes section. YMMV.)

Comment: TJ - thanks for the detailed response. Sadly, I don't have that option available when I am editing the contact.  If I tap the label next to the email address, all it does is open up a new mail addressed to the at person.  I've tried doing a "long" tap, fast tap, click on the address itself, everything.

That being said, I just tried it for the phone numbers in a contact, and that DID have the label screen option you describe above.

Comment: That's really peculiar. I can only assume it is because you are using Outlook (which I assume means your server is Exchange), although that makes *no* sense to me. My only (probably completely unhelpful) suggestion is to pick one of the email addresses as "primary" and move the other one to note field. (Truthfully I've done that with emails and phone numbers to make Siri use faster for those people who I usually email/call at one place. I just keep the other for reference.